# Build aggregator pom for multi module project, with a profile for sub-module

Tags: maven-2, profile, pom.xml, multi-module, aggregator

I have a multi-module project as follows
  --- Module A ( builds war )
  --- Module B
  --- Module C

To build the the multi-module project, I have a aggregator POM that defines the modules.
`<modules>

<module>C</module>

<module>B</module>

<module>A</module>

</modules>`

War file A, has a dependency on module B & module C.

When I build the aggregator pom, I want to build module-B with a particular profile. Is there a way to tell the aggregator pom to build module-B with a particular profile ?

Comment: Would you give an example of what exactly you want when activating the profile? Thanks